# Proof of existence of $L\in R\setminus P$

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages, computability

I saw some proof but I didn't understood it, any simple one?

Comment: Do you understand the time hierarchy theorem?

Comment: Thanks man! @Dmitry

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) for an explanation. In particular, we know (using this theorem) that $P\subsetneq E\subsetneq EXP\subsetneq R$, and we could have added a lot more complexity classes in between them.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this theorem